# Adding index creation/configuration in a Azure search ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-rm-template

There is ways to create a Azure Search Service via ARM template (Example: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/101-azure-search-create/azuredeploy.json).

What I want to know is there a way to define a specific index within the ARM template (fields, data sources, indexers etc)?

I know that there are REST services that you can use in order to create and modify indexes but I do not want a separate script/application to handle that after my resource group and Azure Search Service is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Search does not support managing indexes via ARM templates today. If this capability is important to you, please add an item on [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search) to help us prioritize it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
It is not that important at the moment since there is ways around it.

Answer (score 6):

+1 to Don's comment.  You will need to create the index either using the [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798941.aspx) or the [.NET SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-create-index-dotnet/).  If you happen to be using PowerShell to create the service, you might find the following code helpful which calls the REST API using Invoke-RestMethod and a set of .JSON files that contain the schema for the index and some documents.

```
#------------------------#
# Setting up search index#
#------------------------#
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Content-Type", 'application/json')
$headers.Add("api-key", $searchApiKey)

Write-Host 
Write-Host "Creating Index..."
$schemaFile = "$(Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)\zipcodes.schema"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -TimeoutSec 10000 $searchServiceUrl"/indexes/zipcodes2?api-version=2015-02-28-Preview" -Method Put -Headers $headers -Body "$(get-content $schemaFile)"
Write-Host $response

$jsonFile = "$(Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)\zipcodes1.json"
Write-Host 
Write-Host "Adding Documents from $jsonFile..."
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -TimeoutSec 10000 $searchServiceUrl"/indexes/zipcodes2/docs/index?api-version=2015-02-28-Preview" -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body "$(get-content $jsonFile)"
Write-Host $response
```

Comment: Thank you for the snippet, I ended up doing something similar to this. It will have to do until further support is added!

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot create an index within an ARM template.  The terminology I've read before is that ARM is for managing the Azure control plane.